# How do I use NSRange with this NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrange

I have the following `NSString`:

```
productID = @"com.sortitapps.themes.pink.book";
```

At the end, "book" can be anything.... "music", "movies", "games", etc.

I need to find the third period after the word pink so I can replace that last "book" word with something else. How do I do this with NSRange? Basically I need this:

```
partialID = @"com.sortitapps.themes.pink.";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try a backward search for the dot and use the result to get the desired range:

```
NSString *str = @"com.sortitapps.themes.pink.book";
NSUInteger dot = [str rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch].location;

NSString *newStr =
   [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(dot+1, [str length]-dot-1)
                                withString:@"something_else"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, although this isn't a generic solution for finding characters, in your particular case you can "cheat" and save code by doing this:

```
[productID stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

Essentially, I'm treating the name as a filename and removing the last (and only the last) extension using the NSString method for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]` to split into components, create a new array with your desired values, then use `[NSArray componentsJoinedByString:@"."]` to join your modified array into a string again.

Comment: Although NSRange is the correct solution to this, I ended up using your solution instead because it's easier to understand and manipulate. The reason this really shouldn't be used is because Apple/iOS doesn't guarantee the order of the array will be correct (although it always is in practice).

Comment: Actually, from [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html): _The substrings in the array appear in the order they did in the receiver._

Comment: Yes, my answer is to the question that begat this question :)