# Get a string from a string with length from a location

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a NSString object @"i like to do something".
I want to create a new string from that string with the length of 4 and get from 3rd character.
For example, the result must be @"like".
What can I do in objective-c?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use NSRange with this NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726806/how-do-i-use-nsrange-with-this-nsstring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)range`

```
NSString *string = @"i like to do something";
NSString *substring = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 4)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The [substringWithRange](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange) message will do it.

`substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (2, 6)`